# data subsetting around a specific date

Tags: r, date, subset

I am trying to investigate how stock prices volatility prior and after some specific dates behave. So I  woudl like to be able to select the n points before and after given dates. So as an example if I had the following series:

```
1989-09-25  344.23
1989-09-26  344.33
1989-09-27  345.10
1989-09-28  348.60
1989-09-29  349.15
1989-10-02  350.87
1989-10-03  354.71
1989-10-04  356.94
1989-10-05  356.97
1989-10-06  358.78
1989-10-09  359.80
```

and my date  of interest was 1989-09-29 with a range of say 4 days the function would return a matrix or xts object as:

```
1989-09-25  344.23
1989-09-26  344.33
1989-09-27  345.10
1989-09-28  348.60
**1989-09-29  349.15**
1989-10-02  350.87
1989-10-03  354.71
1989-10-04  356.94
1989-10-05  356.97
```

is there any package out there that i could use or few lines of code that would do the trick ?

Ideally as I would have a vector of dates, the function would return a matrix or an xts object with n columns (i.e one column for each date in the date vector) of  2 x n + 1 observations per columns (so 9 in the example above i.e  4 * 2 + the selected date).....

any help / pointer would be welcome.

Comment: Is this a matrix or `xts` object?

Comment: My data can come in either xts or matrix, whatever makes the manipulation easier...

Comment: You would not normally need any (extra) package for such a problem because dates are comparable in R. Thus, it would be along the lines of `x[x[,1] >= date1 & x[,1] <= date2]`

Comment: In your code date1 an date2   are the start and  end date of  the second series I am showing... my problem is that I do not know ex-ante what those dates are... Stock prices exist only for business days, noty for week end or holidays.. So i can't define date1/date 2 as my initial date +/- a number of points as date 1 or date 2 could be a sarturday , sunday or bank holiday....) .Basicallly what i want is just to specifiy one date and the number of points i want before and after this date out of my initial series....if this make any sense

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table( row.names = NULL, sep=',', text="
1989-09-25,344.23
1989-09-26,344.33
1989-09-27,345.10
1989-09-28,348.60
1989-09-29,349.15
1989-10-02,350.87
1989-10-03,354.71
1989-10-04,356.94
1989-10-05,356.97
1989-10-06,358.78
1989-10-09,359.80")
df[,1] <- as.POSIXct(df[,1])
```

to get a single date:

```
dt <- as.POSIXct('1989-09-29')
idx <- which(df[,1]==dt)
seqidx <- seq(idx, idx+2*4)-4
df[seqidx,2]

[1] 344.23 344.33 345.10 348.60 349.15 350.87 354.71 356.94 356.97
```

to apply it to a list of dates

```
sapply(c(as.POSIXct('1989-09-29'), as.POSIXct('1989-10-02')), 
       FUN=function(dt) {df[seq(which(df[,1]==dt),which(df[,1]==dt)+2*4)-4,2]})


        [,1]   [,2]
 [1,] 344.23 344.33
 [2,] 344.33 345.10
 [3,] 345.10 348.60
 [4,] 348.60 349.15
 [5,] 349.15 350.87
 [6,] 350.87 354.71
 [7,] 354.71 356.94
 [8,] 356.94 356.97
 [9,] 356.97 358.78
```

Comment: H Hubert, looks closer to what i want to get ...but somehow the first line of code return df as being a dataframe of 11 rows by 20 columns...so the second line of code crashes....but the sapply(c(as.Pos... seems right to me.... thank you so much for this, really appreciated

Comment: The read table with space as separator didn't like the SO code formating... should be better now

Comment: Hi Hubert, this is really really great and does exactely what i was after...thank you so much for this, I wish you a great week end !